# ASP.NET Web API not logging exception in application insights when deployed in Azure

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, azure-application-insights

I have enabled application insights logging in my ASP.NET Web API project which is done from a class implementing `IExceptionLogger`. In debug mode it's logging exceptions to application insights using `TrackException()`.

But when the same code is deployed in an Azure App Service, it's **not** sending exception to application insights, but it's able to send data using traces.

After trying lot of different ways (flush also), I have added one method which will log exception in SharePoint list, after that Web API is also able to send data to Application Insights. When commenting out the SharePoint code, the Web API stopped sending exception to Application Insights.

I am not sure whether its happening due to some extra time that `TelemetryClient` is getting due to SharePoint code.

Anyone faced this issue?

Here is the Microsoft doc link which I have followed: [LINK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-exceptions#web-api)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have added the Application Insights logging level in **appsettings.json**

```json
    {
        "Logging": {
            "ApplicationInsights": {
                "LogLevel": {
                "Default": "Trace",
                "Microsoft": "Warning",
                "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
            }
        },
        "LogLevel": {
            "Default": "Information",
            "Microsoft": "Warning",
            "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
            }
        },
        "AllowedHosts": "*",
        "ApplicationInsights": {
            "ConnectionString": "< App insights connection string>"
        }
    }
```

After adding the log level of application insights I can able to see the custom logs and exceptions.

Here you can see the security level to verify the [logging level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/ilogger#logging-level)

[image]

Refer [here](https://digitalworkplace365.wordpress.com/2021/01/12/add-api-request-data-to-application-insights-telemetry-in-asp-net-core-using-filters/amp/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Will check regarding web.config. Also it do log when api get some extra time when connecting to Sharepoint for logging into list.

Comment: My project type is asp.net web api. Not able to resolve the issue.